# how to open HTTPS webservice in iPhone browser programmatically/

Tags: iphone, web-services, https

How to open the HTTPS web service in iPhone browser **programmatically**? I guess we can open the browser with the below syntax only for HTTP url,

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevelopertips.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Can i use the same syntax to open it for HTTPS url also? when i tried, it terminated the application saying that "Service Untrusted Certificate"... How do i continue to further access the HTTPS web service??? Please help me

Thank You.

Comment: It will work for HTTPS too. The part where it fails is your web server having a certificate Safari doesn't recognize as valid.

Comment: @zneak - that should be an answer, not a comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it overriding allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost: in the NSURLRequest class:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(NSHTTPURLRequest)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES; 
}
@end
```

ugly but works.